# Plotting a set of vectors in the form of vector plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, vector, graph

I have a set of 100 vectors on the cartesian grid that need to be represented in a vector plot in python. 
These vectors have been stored using lists.

```
grid = [ [ [v1x,v1y] , [v2x,v2y] , ..., [v10x,v10y] ],
         [ [v11x,v11y] , [v12x,v12y] , ..., [v20x,v20y] ],  
         [ [v21x,v21y] , [v22x,v22y] , ..., [v30x,v30y] ],
         ...
         [ [v91x,v92y] , [v93x,v94y] , ..., [v100x,v100y] ] ]
```

This multidimensional list contains information about each vector as well as the position. To access any vector at a random position, the following operation must give us the vector at coordinate (i,j) on the grid:

```
grid[i][j]
```

For example, the statement:

```
grid[2][4]
```

will give us the vector at coordinates (2,4) to be:

```
[v24x,v24y]
```

How can I represent this information as a vector plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way, convert your 3d list of lists of lists into an `ndarray`,
then slice it to select the u (x direction) component of each vector,
and the v (y direction) component of each vector. then plot with `matplotlib.pyplot.quiver()`  NOTE: for simplicity I started numbering vectors at 0, 0  instead of 1, 1 used in your initial question

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

grid = [ 
        [ [1, 5] , [-3, 0] , [2, 4], [-3, 1] ],
        [ [2, 2] , [-1, -2] , [0, 1], [0, 0] ],  
        [ [3, 1] , [4, 2] , [2, 1], [4, 2] ],
]

grid = np.array(grid)

u = grid[:,:,0]    # slice x direction component into u array
v = grid[:,:,1]    # slice y direction component into v array

plt.quiver(u, v)   # plot it!
plt.show()

# if u and v are too dense we could subsample with another slice

u = u[::2, ::2]    # pick out every other vector in the x dimension
v = v[::2, ::2]    # pick out every other vector in the y dimension

plt.quiver(u, v)   # plot it again!
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh. This code is nice. Pretty straight forward. Other sources on the net were doing something else with meshgrids, etc. that were difficult to understand. I do have a problem though. The size of my array is 1000x1000. Therefore, due to the large size, I am getting a black screen. I would assume that we would want to ignore some of these points. How can I do that?

Comment: if your matrix coordinates didn't line up exactly with your vector position coordinates, ie if vector 0,0 wasn't at position 0,0 then meshgrid would be useful to create a SECOND matrix of vector origins usually called x and y and you would have called quiver(u, v, x, y).  but in your case the vector positions matched the matrix coordinates so we were able to use the simplier form of calling quiver(u, v)

Comment: to get past the black screen problem you could do a simple subsample of the u and v matrices using another slice:
u = u[::2, ::2]
v = v[::2, ::2]
this would pick out every other vector to plot, I added some more code to my existing answer to illustrate

Comment: subsampling this way just throws away the unused vectors so if you wanted to hang onto that data in some form you might want to look at doing a convolution on u and v to take each point and replace it with the average of itself and its eight neighbors and THEN do the subsample

Comment: oh also, if my answer is working for ya could you mark it as accepted when you get a chance?  thanks!